# Build a PHP Array string from Database field value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So in my database I have a field that holds values in this format "MSFT,AAPL,SNAP,MCD"

How can I setup these values in this format to PHP such as this

```
$symbols = ["MSFT","AAPL","SNAP","MCD"];
```

I know Im going to need to explode (comma delimited) values but cant put my finger on it.

After I would explode the values and I would then use count with a while loop to build the string.

In the end I would think it would look something like this

```
$new_string = '"MSFT","AAPL","SNAP","MCD"';
```

Then I think could just do this?

```
$symbols = [$new_string];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this.

```
<?php
    $str = "MSFT,AAPL,SNAP,MCD";
    $symbols = (explode(",",$str));
    var_dump($symbols); #displays the array values;
    var_dump(count($symbols)); #array count
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking on how to build this 
$symbols = ["MSFT","AAPL","SNAP","MCD"]; with the values from the database

Comment: using the answer given would give you the expected result. dumping the values would give you something like this `[0] => MSFT[1] => AAPL [2] =>SNAP [3] => MCD` which is exactly the same when you dump the `$symbols` containing your desired format